# Create a new associative array from a single-element associative array containing related comma-separated values

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am trying to create a new array structure from a single-element associative array where the key and the value are both comma-separated strings with related data.

Which array function should I use to do this?

Input array:

```
[
  "id,zip,state,city,county,territory,price" => "1,90001,CA,Los Angeles,Los Angeles,Orange CA,40"
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    "id" => 1,
    "zip" => 90001,
    "state" => "CA",
    "city" => "Los Angeles",
    "county" => "Los Angeles",
    "territory" => "Orange CA",
    "price" => 40
]
```

Comment: Hello, could you include the code you have tried to get the output you need and perhaps indicate the difficulties?

Comment: @Romil Perhaps most importantly... _Why_ is your data originating in this format?  It looks like you seeking a bandaid for a broken bone.

Answer (score 0):

`"id,zip,state,city,county,territory,price"` is one key, not multiple. So you have to split them.

```php
$old = ["id,zip,state,city,county,territory,price" => "1,90001,CA,Los Angeles,Los Angeles,Orange CA,40"];

$keys = explode(',', $key = array_key_first($old));
$values = explode(',', $old[$key]);
$new = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Gives

```
array(7) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["zip"]=>
  string(5) "90001"
  ["state"]=>
  string(2) "CA"
  ["city"]=>
  string(11) "Los Angeles"
  ["county"]=>
  string(11) "Los Angeles"
  ["territory"]=>
  string(9) "Orange CA"
  ["price"]=>
  string(2) "40"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost identical to @Markus's, but `key()` can be used in more php versions.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dbRvb))

```
$array = [
    "id,zip,state,city,county,territory,price" => "1,90001,CA,Los Angeles,Los Angeles,Orange CA,40"
];

$key = key($array);
var_export(
    array_combine(
        explode(',', $key),
        explode(',', $array[$key])
    )
);
```